# MVC 4 JsonResult rendering raw string instead of View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

This is a real beginner question and hopefully you would be able to help me with a quick answer.

When I call my action of type JsonResult the view renders as raw Json and not as the expected defined view that I have created.

This is all that I see in the browser:

```
[{"Name":"xx","Description":"xx","Address":"xx","Town":"xx","PostCode":"xx","Enabled":true,"pkId":1},{"Name":"xx","Description":"xx","Address":"xx","Town":"xx","PostCode":"xxx","Enabled":true,"pkId":3}]
```

Here's my action:

```
public JsonResult SubmitFeedback()
    {
        PropertyInspectionContext context = new PropertyInspectionContext();
        var prop = context.Property;
        return Json(prop, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is wrong with this ? you have return Json so it is the response you get. If you want view then return viewresult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created JsonResult ( Json) in return so it is return JsonString.

If you want View should be return with Html markup and model combine then you should have to return View Result.

```
public ActionResult SubmitFeedback()
    {
        PropertyInspectionContext context = new PropertyInspectionContext();
        var prop = context.Property;

        //return Json(prop, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return View(your view name,prop);   

    }
```